# Extracting one text files from multiple zip archives in R

Tags: r, zip, text-files, extract

I am trying to extract one text file from each of the zip files located in one folder. Then I want to combine those text files into one dataframe.

The folder has multiple Zip files:

```
pf_0915.zip
pf_0914.zip
pf_0913.zip
.....
```

Inside of those zip files are multiple text files. I am only interested in the one called abc.txt. This is a fixed width format file without header. I have already set up a read for this file using read_fwd. Since all the extracted text files have the same name, it might be better to rename them according the name of their archive. i.e. the abc.txt from pf_0915.zip could be called abc_0915.txt. Once they are all read they should be combined into a large file called abcCombined.txt.

Or as each new abc.txt file is read, we could add it to the abcCombined.txt.

I have tried various version of unzip() and unz() without much success. This was done without looping through all the zip files. And finally, this directory contains many zip files, are there ways to read only some of them by using pattern matching like grep. I would for example be interested in reading only September files, those .._09...txt.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share a sample code to see what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

The following:

1. Creates a vector of the files in a directory
2. Uses the `list` parameter to `unzip()` to see the metadata for the contents
3. Builds a regular expression to find only the target file (I did that in the event your use-case generalizes to a broader pattern)
4. Tests if any of the files meet your criteria
5. Keeps only those files into a resultant vector
6. Iterates over that vector and

   - Extracts only the target file into a temporary directory
   - Reads it into a `data.frame`
   - Ultimately binds the individual `data.frame`s into one big one

You can write out the resultant combined `data.frame` however you wish.

```
library(purrr)

target_dir <- "so"
extract_file <- "abc.txt"

list.files(target_dir, full.names=TRUE) %>% 
  keep(~any(grepl(sprintf("^%s$", extract_file), unzip(., list=TRUE)$Name))) %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    td <- tempdir()
    read.fwf(unzip(x, extract_file, exdir=td), widths=c(4,1,4,2))
  }) -> combined_df
```

The version below just expands some of the shortcuts in the one above:

```
only_files_with_this_name <- function(zip_path, name) {
  zip_contents <- unzip(zip_path, list=TRUE)
  look_for <- sprintf("^%s$", name)
  any(grepl(look_for, zip_contents$Name))
}

list.files(target_dir, full.names=TRUE) %>% 
  keep(only_files_with_this_name, name=extract_file)) %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    td <- tempdir()
    file_in_zip <- unzip(x, extract_file, exdir=td)
    read.fwf(file_in_zip, widths=c(4,1,4,2))
    unlink(file_in_zip)
  }) -> combined_df
```

Comment: Works as advertised. Amazing time saver. Extracted 15 fixed witdth text files from 15 large zip files, combining then and cleaning then up in less than 10 sec, resulting in a clean 2.5 million row dataframe - YES!  Could you explain what is going on in the keep(... line of the code? Thanks again.

Comment: That's #3, #4 & #5. The `unzip()` returns a list of files in a zip archive with a few columns of infio. The `$Name`  retrieves only the name of the file. That gets passed to `grepl()` which searches for an exact match (you can tweak the regex to be more permissive if need be). The `any()` returns a single `TRUE` if any of the results of the `grepl()` are `TRUE`. `keep()` only keeps the ones that are `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to add an additional filter to keep only certain zip files, in this case those that include "_09" in the name. I tried to replace the first line with keep(~any(grepl("_09", list.files(target_dir, full.names=TRUE)))), but I got an error saying argument ".p" is missing, with no default.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment because of my low reputation, so although this is a partial answer:

If you know the file name within the various zips the syntax to get just that file would be something like the following:

```
my_data<-read.csv(unz("pf_0915.zip","abc.txt"))
```

This is the code for a csv obviously, not a fixed width text, but if you already have that set up, it'll be something like

```
my_data<-read_fwd(unz("pf_0915.zip","abc.txt") ... )
```

with all your other parameters in the ...

You can do this in a loop if you have many zips, and accumulate them in a data frame, data table, whatever structure floats your boat...