# Batch reading compressed CSV files in R

Tags: r, csv, zip

Newbie here. I have 1000 compressed CSV files that I need to read and row bind. My problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537306/extracting-one-text-files-from-multiple-zip-archives-in-r), but with two differences:

a) File names are of different lengths and not sequential, in this form:

```
"members_[name of company]_[state code].csv"`
```

I have two vectors, `company` and `states` with the required codes. So, I've built a vector of all the files I need with this code:

```
combinations <- expand.grid(company, states)
csvfiles <- paste0("members_" ,
            combinations$Var1, "_",
            combinations$Var2,".csv" )
```

so it has all the filenames I need (20 companies X 50 states). But I am lost as to how to cycle through all zip files. There are 10 other CSVs inside those zip files, but I only need the ones described above.

b) When decompressed, the files expand to a directory structure such as this:

```
/files/member_database/members/state/members_[name of company]_[state code].csv
```

but when I try to read the CSV from the zip file using

```
data <- read.csv(unz("members_GE_FL.zip", "members_GE_FL.csv"), header=F,  sep=":")
```

it returns the 'cannot open connection' message. Adding the path such as `./files/member_database/members/state/members_GE_FL.csv` doesn't work either.

Then, I'm not sure if the command `read.csv(unz(csvfiles...` would make it read the names in my `csvfiles`, but I'm not sure if that's because of the above or if the command is wrong altogether.

Any help is appreciated -- insights, docs I should look at, etc. Again, I'm NOT trying to get people to do my work. As I type, I have 37 tabs open (many from SO), and have already spent 22 hours on this thing alone. I've learned [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986818/automate-zip-file-reading-in-r) and others how to read a file within a ZIP and from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data) how to extract and import data. Still, I can't piece it all together. I've only started with R a few months ago, and have no prior experience as a programmer.

Comment: What has all this got to do with [tag:batch-file]? Please read the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info) **before** applying tags! Perhaps you meant [tag:batch-processing] (check the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-processing/info)!)?

Comment: Sorry, batch-file was suggested automatically. Yes, I would have meant batch-processing.

Comment: What does `unzip(members_GE_FL.zip, list=TRUE)` return? That should probably tell you what strings `unz()` is expecting.

Comment: It returns:```Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
  cannot locate file 'members_GE_FL.csv' in zip file 'members_GE_FL.zip'```

Comment: Oops, i meant `unzip("members_GE_FL.zip", list=TRUE)`. That should list all the files in the archive. Did you still pass that to `unz()`? Or what did you run exactly? Because i'm not sure why `members_GE_FL.csv` would be in the error message. That seems odd.

Comment: That command shows indeed all 10 files within the zip. I've built a vector with the filenames of the ZIP archives and the filenames I need, but I am not sure how to cycle through those vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect all that was missing was the correct path to the file in the archive: neither `"members_GE_FL.csv"` nor `"./files/member_database/members/state/members_GE_FL.csv"` will work.
But `"files/member_database/members/state/members_GE_FL.csv"` (without the initial dot) should.

For the sake of completeness, here is a complete example:

Let's create some dummy data, three files named `out-1.csv`, `out-2.csv`, `out-3.csv` and zip them in `dummy-archive.zip`:

```
if (!dir.exists("data")) dir.create("data")
if (!dir.exists("data/dummy-files")) dir.create("data/dummy-files")
for (i in 1:3)
  write.csv(data.frame(foo = 1:2, bar = 7:8), paste0("data/dummy-files/out-", i, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
zip("data/dummy-archive.zip", "data/dummy-files")
```

Now let's assume we're looking for 3 other files, two of which are in the archive, one is not:

```
files_to_find <- c("out-2.csv", "out-3.csv", "out-4.csv")
```

List the files in the archive, and name them for the sake of clarity:

```
files_in_archive <- unzip("data/dummy-archive.zip", list = TRUE)$Name
files_in_archive <- setNames(files_in_archive, basename(files_in_archive))

#                  dummy-files                    out-2.csv 
#          "data/dummy-files/" "data/dummy-files/out-2.csv" 
#                    out-3.csv                    out-1.csv 
# "data/dummy-files/out-3.csv" "data/dummy-files/out-1.csv"
```

Find the indices of files we're looking for in the archive, and read them like you intended to (with `read.csv(unz(....))`):

```
i <- basename(files_in_archive) %in% files_to_find
res <- lapply(files_in_archive[i], function(f) read.csv(unz("data/dummy-archive.zip", f)))

# $`out-2.csv`
#   foo bar
# 1   1   7
# 2   2   8
# 
# $`out-3.csv`
#   foo bar
# 1   1   7
# 2   2   8
```

Clean-up:

```
unlink(c("data/dummy-files/", "data/dummy-archive.zip"), recursive = TRUE)
```

Comment: @a p o m: your suspicion is correct. The `list_files` command returned the path without "./" . Let me try this and get back to you. Thank you!